# App inventor - Multiline Notifier Message

Tags: android, app-inventor

I'm trying to use line breaks in the 'message' section of a notifier in App Inventor. However, the line is not *breaking*, so to speak. As the internet told me, I was supposed to use either '`\n`' or '`\n\n`', but after trying both the lines are still not *broken*. Below is the "code" that I am using.  [image]

Could someone please provide feedback regarding my given problem, thanks.

Comment: [New formatting possibilities with the Notifier](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2notifier)

Comment: see also the [documentation](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/userinterface.html#Notifier)

Comment: @taifun when commenting 'use <br>' was too hard...

Comment: Before asking looking into the documentation was too hard for you? And now you are complaining about the answer, which is a link explaining all the possibilities? Is this, what you are trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

write `\n` between single quotes like `'\n'` and execute your code with emulator
after you see those single quotes in the output, delete them, just leave `\n`
it is going to work.
if it does not, remove string block, and add a new one.

I think it's a bug.